# Solving a quadratic recurrence?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

I have a quadratic recurrence relation of the form

$$rV(n) = \pi(n) - V(n+1) \cdot V(n)/2$$
where $\pi(n) > 0$  and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi(n) = \pi^*$.

As $n \to \infty$, I can define $V^{\ast}$ as the unique positive solution to $rV^{\ast} = \pi^{\ast} - (V^{\ast})^2/2$

Is there a closed form solution for $V(n)$ or guarantee on how quickly $V(n)$ converges to $V^{\ast}$?

Comment: It seems like your recurrence would actually be $V(n+1)=2r-2\pi(n)/V(n)$. That's more or less the form of a continued fraction.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to determine whether the continued fraction converges?

Comment: I believe so but I'm by no means an expert in this. See for instance the discussion of convergence here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Simple_convergence_concepts. In particular, note the closing comment: "The [Śleszyński–Pringsheim theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aleszy%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Pringsheim_theorem) provides a sufficient condition for convergence."